# Jumping from one DB row to another using Fast Reports

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am working with Delphi 16 and Fast Reports 4.1. Embarcadero Edidion.

Roughly, my question is :
Is there a way to force frxReport (connected to a Data Base) to skip some of the table entries during report generation?

What I mean can be illustrated as follows:

Assume that we have a large table from the database, one with 1000 entries, and assume that we want to generate a report filled with data from this table, with one page per entry. 
Naturally, 1000 pages report will be a bit too much to handle, so we need a way to tell Fast Report which entries of the table to use while preparing the report.

To select only a subset of all entries of the table, I use DBGrid where I set the DBGrid.Options.dgMultiselect := True and select the desired rows with mouse clicks. Then I copy the selected rows into a seperate TClientDataSet(named TempDataSet) component, after which I set the current report's data set to the newly created TempDataSet ( 'frxDataSet1.DataSet := TempDataSet' ) and launch prepare report.

This seems to be ok, but in the context of the application I am programming, is unacceptable. So going back to the original question: Is there a way to control which entries in 'frxDBDataset1.DataSet' must be visited when 'frxReport1.PrepareReport();' is called ?

Thank you

Comment: All filter and sort procedures should take place before passing data to report. You can use a TClientDataSet for storing the filtered and sorted rows (like you already do) :o)

Comment: As an alternative you can try TfrxUserDataset

Comment: The thing is, half of my application assumes that frxReport's data set is of type TADOTable. Bad application design, I guess. That is why I am looking for an alternative. 
is it possible then to create and fill with data a TADOTable object without associating it with a concrete database table? I mean kind of in-memory TADOTable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resort to any of this methods:

### Filter

Your original DataSet (if the DataSet is capable of filtering). You usually write a *a la SQL* filter, like this:

```
MyDataSet.Filter := 'MYCOLUMN in (''a'', ''b'', ''c'')';
MyDataSet.Filtered := True;
```

Or write a `OnFilterRecord` event to exclude/include the records you want to show in the report.

```
procedure TMyForm.MyDataSetFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := (DataSet.FieldByName('MYFIELD').AsInteger mod 7 = 0) or 
            (DataSet.FieldByName('MYOTHERFIELD').AsInteger in MySetOfValues);
end;
```

### TFrxDBDataSet events

You can also resort to the events of the `TfrxDBDataSet` component you usually use to bind your report to the data. Write a `OnOpen`, `OnFirst`, `OnNext`, `OnCheckEOF` event handlers to prevent the report to include all the records by "stoping" only on the records of your interest.

For example, if you want to print each second row, you could write this:

```
procedure TMyForm.fdsEstPagosNext(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyDataSet.Next; 
  MyDataSet.Next; //advance not one, but two records.
end;
```

Comment: Well, thank you for the informative reply. I will give it a try.

Comment: I did it as you suggested and it works. 
I have another question.
What is the fastest way to check for each record (row) of the Table, whether or not it (the current record) has been selected by the user ?

I am thinking something like this: 'DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Find(ADOTable1.Bookmark, index)' should return true if ADOTable1.Bookmark is inside DBGrid1's selected rows bookmark list. This, however does not seem to work for me. When I call ADOTable1.Bookmark , it returns an empty Array (the property Bookmark is a dynamic byte array).

Comment: You should first read the documentation for that properties (which usually include examples), and if you still are in doubt, you better publish a new question on the site. ;)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a little off topic, refering to your last comment, it is possible to use Adodatasets as Memorytables

```
var
 I:Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to AdoDataset1.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      Adodataset2.FieldDefs.Add(AdoDataset1.Fields[i].FieldName
                               ,AdoDataset1.Fields[i].Datatype
                               ,AdoDataset1.Fields[i].Size);
    end;
      Adodataset2.CreateDataSet;
                                // just as example     
  While not AdoDataset1.Eof do  // here would be you code for inserting selected Rows
    begin
     AdoDataset2.Append;
    for I := 0 to AdoDataset1.FieldCount - 1 do
      begin
        Adodataset2.Fields[i].Assign(Adodataset1.Fields[i]);
      end;
    AdoDataset2.Post;
    AdoDataset1.Next;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggested, but it wouldnt work because many of my application's functions have TADOTable, rather than TDataSet, as an input argument. And I need to use these functions without duplicating code. The solution I attempted is to create a subclass of TADOTable which contains a TClientDataSet as a private field and "behaves" like a TClientDataSet but "looks" like TADOTable . A little dangerous, but I did not know how to do the Filtering as suggested by jachguate